# Как считать данные из таблицы TableView.Java

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Как считать данные которые только что были отредактированы пользователем из таблицы TableView и сохранить.Java.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно расплывчатый вопрос. Если вообщем, то данные в TableVeiw представлены в виде набора данных javafx.collections.ObservableList. Сначала объявляете этот список, потом его добавляете в таблицу.

```
private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...
table.setItems(data);
```

При редактировании списка таблица автоматически обновляется.
Соответственно, отредактированные данные берем из списка.
Почитайте пример: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm